# Redis GUI Redis-commander working on Docker - ERROR: Status: reconnecting

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I have installed Redis GUI redis-commander by using https://github.com/joeferner/redis-commander

Redis running on localhost:6379 as a container at docker.

This says if I run redis on localhost:6379, all I need to get started is;

*docker run --rm --name redis-commander -d -p 8081:8081 ghcr.io/joeferner/redis-commander:latest*

[image: redis-commander]

**But I encountered with this problem... Is there anyone who got this error  and found a solution for this ??**

Comment: Could you provide the command you have used to run redis as a docker container?

Comment: docker run -d -p 6379:6379 --name some-redis redis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things you have to take into account.

- Redis commander is running inside a container so localhost no longer points to your laptop/desktop/developing machine/server. It points to the container itself where no redis is running. So it will never connect. You need to point to the other container.
- For this, you should be using `some-redis` (the name of the container) instead of `localhost`. In Redis Commander click *more* and *add server* to add a new connection
- But this will not work unless both containers are running inside the same network.

You need to create first a new docker network

```
docker network create redis
```

And then run your containers using this parameter `--network=redis`

More about docker network [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/)
More about docker run with networks [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings)

Comment: For me, as default they all work in the same network for now. But name of the container solved my problem, thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the name of database "container_name" was different in "REDIS_HOSTS" parameter:

Services:

db:
container_name: redis_db

redis-commander:
environment:
- REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis_db:6379

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5edg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Define the redis-commander network as redis network:

```
redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
        - ./docker/redis/data:/data
    networks:
        - app-network #same network here
redis-commander:
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    container_name: redis-commander
    environment:
        - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
    ports:
        - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
        - redis
    networks:
        - app-network #and here
```

You can't forget to add network in the end of docker-composer file:

```
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```